# Display dicom or raw images in 3D

Tags: java, 3d, dicom

I was wondering what tool can I use to make a single slice (image) into 3D. I can open dicom and raw images in my program but I want to display these images in 3D (just a single image rather than the whole stack). I used some of ImageJ files to open images but I don't like how ImageJ displays the stack in 3D and it doesn't really display a single image in 3d. My program is coded in java and I would like a tool that can be easily integrated into eclipse Kepler. I have found many tools like jogl, java 3d, java 3d workbench, vtk, etc. but I don't know which one to use or are there any other programs that are easier to use or integrate into the system.

EDIT:
I want to do something like this... http://www.welfenlab.de/fileadmin/forschung/gebiete/YaDiV/2008_07_18_Screenshot_YaDiV_1.png

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "display a single slice in 3D"?  A single slice is 2D, what would be the third dimension that you are interested in?  A single slice is an X,Y graph of 16-bit greyscale intensities, guessing that you are referring to CT or MR images here.

Comment: @ChrisO So the user has a stack of images, where they pick a slice/image from that stack- that slice has x-y coordinate (which is basically the 2D image) but it also has a z-coordinate (like where each slice was taken in the MRI). I want to convert that single slice into a 3D image. Does that kind of makes sense?

Comment: @ChrisO see edit. Thats what I kind of want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/index.html) which can be used to create three-dimensional models from two-dimensional slices. I haven't personally used it, but it looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: I have been using ImageJ but the volumeJ and volume viewer all require stacks. They don't compute a 3D with a single slice. Do you know of any plugin that do?

Comment: Sorry, I admittedly skimmed over your question and didn't see that you were already using it. So you want to project a single image into 3D space? I would suggest finding an alternative course of action, or if that's not possible, using a library such as LWJGL. It's certainly a bulky addition, but it would make the task much easier, as you could just convert it to a textured quad.

Comment: @NewProgrammer In order to compute the 3D you will need to process the stack.  The single slice in only 2D.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [XTK](https://github.com/xtk/X)?  in particular, lesson 17 seems to be exactly what you are looking for.  it is in Javascript, so to integrate into your Java application, you should be able to use one of the many Java/Javascript bridges out there.